# How to change the Option menu icon in the Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet, android-actionbar

On Honeycomb, when the options are hidden (not ifRoom), they are displayed in a Spinner in an option menu.
I simply would like to know how to change the icon of this option menu (furthest to the right).
By default, the icon is just three lines and 3 dots on ICS.

Thanks !

Comment: See similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733312/changing-overflow-icon-in-the-action-bar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See more attributes from your android sdk installation, in platforms/android-XX/data/res/values/style.xml

Here is menu overflow action button style definition:

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/action_menu_overflow_description</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the officialy documentation telling you how to customize the action bar to the up most.

[Customizaing the action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: I used parent="android:style/Theme.Holo" and it then let me designate put a custom overflow icon.