# Android ActionBar (Sherlock) - Changing menu icon color / transparency

Tags: android, colors, transparency, android-actionbar

Is there a way to make to change the color of the 3 dots of the menu icon?
I'd like to make them completely white without any transparency but haven't found anything in the android styles/themes?

FYI: I'm using actionbarsherlock.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because they aren't made in the code just search the image `com_actionbarsherlock/res/drawable-hdpi/abs__list_divider_holo_light.9.png` in your drawable directory there you can change the color of this image.

Comment: Hmm, do I have a chance to "overload" this image by putting a same file with the same name into my own "drawable-hdpi" directory?

But I assume this wouldn't work either due to different packages...

Comment: um that will not work because abs is looking up the image in his own directories

Comment: Ok, just as I thought. Changed the "abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark.png" asset did the trick.

But now ActionBarSherlocks intelligent behaviour comes in my way: Android 2.x uses my manipulated menu icons, but Android 4.x uses its native ones...

Any chance to do something against that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733312/changing-overflow-icon-in-the-action-bar