# Styling Action Bar Text Color - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

```
<style name="Theme.RateItTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Text</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#2E495E</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ECECEC</item>
</style>
```

I have been able to change the background, but not the text color. Or the overflow menu  "three dots".  My code is above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBar text color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move your `titleTextStyle` attribute into your `MyActionBar` style. Do you understand why it's supposed to be placed there rather than where you had it originally?

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#2E495E</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Text</item>
</style>
```

As far as changing the Overflow icon, I think that's what mean when you say "three dots", [I've already written a post about that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733538/420015)

Comment: Ok thanks, I see what I did wrong there.  Hey, where do I get a drawable for the overflow menu in white?  I didn't see it in the android source files.

Comment: Download the official [Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack).

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- For honeycomb and up -->
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.RateItTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionBarText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#2E495E</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ECECEC</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I don't think the `android:actionMenuTextColor` is necessary. The other pieces seem to do the trick. Thanks!