# Change Android ActionBar overflow icon in code

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to change overflow icon in code?

I read this solution: [Changing overflow icon in the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733312/changing-overflow-icon-in-the-action-bar)

But I need to make it in code, to select white or grey style during runtime.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change this in a theme.

One potential solution would be to call `setTheme` as the very first thing in `onCreate` with different themes depending on whether you needed white or gray.