# Styling icon of MenuItem on Android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, menuitem

I'd like to stylize the three dots of the button of menuitem (like on Nexus Phone)

It's possible without Sherlock ActionBar or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733538/1207921), it explains how to do it for both regular and SherlockActionBar