# Custom overflow icon in Contextual ActionBar only

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, contextual-action-bar

I have a dark ActionBar with a light Contextual ActionBar for `ActionMode`s. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733312/changing-overflow-icon-in-the-action-bar) about changing the overflow icon in the ActionBar, and it works, but I need a way to change it only for the Contextual ActionBar. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a theme just for the overflow icon then use `ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme` in `ActionMode.Callback.onCreateActionMode`. For instance:

**style**

```
<style name="Widget.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/your_overflow_icon</item>
</style>

<style name="CAB.Overflow" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

**ActionMode**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    setTheme(R.style.CAB_Overflow);
    // Inflate your menu items
    return true;
}
```

**Normal** and **CAB**

[image: Before] [image: After]