# Change ActionMode Overflow icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

Is there a way to change the ActionMode Overflow icon without changing the icon for the "normal" ActionBar?

Answer (score 10):

> I still need to figure out how to only change the Overflow-Icon inside of the ActionMode-Actionbar as I changed my Overflow-Icon in the default-Actionbar which is not visible in the ActionMode-Actionbar (and no, I don't want to change the background of my ActionMode-Actionbar!)

Okay.

Let's start with defining some styles. I will try and explain why we are defining them in this fashion:

```
// This is just your base theme. It will probably include a lot more stuff.
// We are going to define the style 'OverflowActionBar' next.

<style name="BaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    ....
    ....
    ....
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowActionBar</item>
</style>

// Assigning a parent to this style is important - we will inherit two attributes -
// the background (state-selector) and the content description

<style name="OverflowActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/overflow_menu_light</item>
</style>

// Next up is an extension to our 'BaseTheme'. Notice the parent here.

<style name="ChangeOverflowToDark" parent="@style/BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowActionMode</item>
</style>

// One last thing is to define 'OverflowActionMode'. Again, we inherit useful
// attributes by assigning 'Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow' as the parent.

<style name="OverflowActionMode" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/overflow_menu_dark</item>
</style>
```

All our work with `styles.xml` is done. The very last bit happens at runtime. I suppose you already have an implementation of `ActionMode.Callback`.

In your activity, define a method -  `changeOverflowIcon()`:

```
public void changeOverflowIcon() {
    getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.ChangeOverflowToDark, true);
}
```

You will be calling this method from `onCreateActionMode(...)` of your `ActionMode.Callback` implementation:

```
public class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        changeOverflowIcon()

        // other initialization

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(final ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {}
}
```

A bit of explanation:

The assignment in 'BaseTheme' is for the `ActionBar`. It will pick the drawable `overflow_menu_light` since we are assigning it in the base theme of your app.

```
getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.ChangeOverflowToDark, true)
```

The second argument `true` forces the current theme to override the old attributes with the new ones. Since we only define one attribute in `ChangeOverflowToDark`, its value is overwritten. The `ActionBar` is not affected because it has already used the old attribute. But, the action mode is yet to be created (it will be created when we return `true` from `onCreateActionMode(...)`). When the action mode checks for this attributes value, it gets the new one.

**There's more...**

The answer given by Manish is quite awesome. I could have never thought of using the content description to find the exact `ImageButton`. *But what if you could find the `ImageButton` using a straightforward `findViewById()`?*

Here's how you can:

First, we will need unique ids. If your project doesn't currently have a `res/values/ids.xml` file, create one. Add a new id to it:

```
<item type="id" name="my_custom_id" />
```

The setup I discussed above will remain the same. The only difference will be in `OverflowActionMode` style:

```
<style name="OverflowActionMode" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/overflow_menu_dark</item>
    <item name="android:id">@id/my_custom_id</item>
</style>
```

*The id we defined above will be assigned to the `ImageButton` when we call `getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.ChangeOverflowToDark, true);`*

I'll borrow the code snippet from Manish's answer here:

```
private ActionMode.Callback mCallback = new ActionMode.Callback()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode( ActionMode mode, Menu menu )
    {

        mDecorView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) mDecorView.findViewById(R.id.my_custom_id);
                // Update the image here.
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.custom);
            }          
        }, 500); // 500 ms is quite generous // I would say that 50 will work just fine

        return true;
    }  
}
```

**Best of both worlds?**

Let's say we need `R.drawable.overflow_menu_light` for `ActionBar` and `R.drawable.overflow_menu_dark` for `ActionMode`.

Styles:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    ....
    ....
    ....
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowActionMode</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowActionMode" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/overflow_menu_dark</item>
    <item name="android:id">@id/my_custom_id</item>
</style>
```

As defined in our style, the `ActionBar` will pick `R.drawable.overflow_menu_dark` - but don't we need the *light* version for the `ActionBar`? Yes - we will assign that in the activity's `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)` callback:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) 
                                 getWindow().getDecorView()
                                .findViewById(R.id.my_custom_id);
            if (ib != null)
                ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.overflow_menu_light);
        }
    }, 50L);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

We are doing this here because before `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`, the `ImageButton` would not have been created.

Now, we *don't* need to deal with `ActionMode` - because it will pick the `dark` drawable from the theme.

My apologies for this gigantic post. I *really* hope it helps.

Comment: This is just an amazing explanation! Your first tutorial worked out quite well! In my opinion this is a way more beautiful than dealing with Handlers and Runnables.... Thanks for that! :))

Comment: Tried the first solution with styles, works for me for pre Android 5.0, but does not work with Android Lollipop 5.0. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 3):

`ImageButton` is the widget used to display the menu overflow. `actionOverflowButtonStyle` is used for styling the `ImageButton`. This styling is applied in [ActionMenuPresenter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuPresenter.java?av=f#590).

```
private class OverflowMenuButton extends ImageButton implements ActionMenuChildView {
   public OverflowMenuButton(Context context) {
      super(context, null, com.android.internal.R.attr.actionOverflowButtonStyle);
      ...
   }
}
```

`ActionMenuPresenter` class is used for building action menus both in `action bar` and `action modes`. Hence by overriding the theme files will apply same style in both modes. The only way to accomplish is it programatically as it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106474/2083078) for the `action bar`.

Here is the code of how it can be done for `action mode` overflow icon. You can assign the `drawable` to the `ImageButton` in `ActionMode.Callback.onPrepareActionMode` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ViewGroup mDecorView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Assign mDecorView to later use in action mode callback
        mDecorView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mCallback = new ActionMode.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode( ActionMode mode, Menu menu )
        {
            // We have to update the icon after it is displayed, 
            // hence this postDelayed variant. 
            // This is what I don't like, but it is the only way to move forward.

            mDecorView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<View> outViews = new ArrayList<View>();
                    // The content description of overflow button is "More options".
                    // If you want, you can override the style and assign custom content
                    // description and use it here.
                    mDecorView.findViewsWithText(outViews, "More Options", View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
                    if(!outViews.isEmpty()) {
                        View v = outViews.get(0);
                        if(v instanceof ImageButton) {
                            ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) v;
                            // Update the image here.
                            btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.custom);
                        }                       
                    }
                }               
            }, 500);

            return true;
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've already seen this way of implementing this but thought that there has to be a way to do it in xml. However, your explanation is very good and I now think the way you suggest is the only way to do this... Have fun with the bounty (in 14 hrs...)

Comment: @Frame91 Just a suggestion..make complete use of your bounty offer. You can keep this answer in unaccepted state, so that others will make an attempt to provide (may be) a better solution that this. When the bounty nears it expiry time you can assign the bounty manually.

Comment: Yeah you're right - but as you explained nobody is going to submit a plain xml-solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that using styles:

**ActionBarSherlock:**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyTheme.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.OverFlow" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/YOUR_ICON_GOES_HERE</item>
</style>
```

**ActioBar:**

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyTheme.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/YOUR_ICON_GOES_HERE</item>
</style>
```

Make sure to set MyTheme in the manifest.

Comment: Yes I did that for the ActionBar but I need the Holo.Dark icon for the ActionBar and the Holo.Light icon for the ActionMode.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change the ActionMode Overflow icon without changing the icon for the "normal" ActionBar?

Regards how to change the overflow icon, I think there are many answers as above.

If you just want to change the color of the overflow icon, you can use a simple way.

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.xxxx.Light.NoActionBar.xxx">
    ...           
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionMode.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionMode.OverFlow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/black</item>  #or any color you want.#
</style>
```

It works for me. I investigated a bit, just check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/vqx1ov  you will know the reason.

And I don't suggest to set the colour of colorControlNormal, it will change the color of "back arrow" and "overflow icon" on ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just want a different color of the three dots icon, and to achieve it, I set `<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/Widget.ActionMode.ActionBar</item>` in my theme, and `Widget.ActionMode.ActionBar` looks like below:

```
    <style name="Widget.ActionMode.ActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">the color I want</item>
    </style>
```