# AppCompat Toolbar: Change Overflow Icon Color in ActionMode

Tags: android, overflow, toolbar, android-appcompat, actionmode

With the AppCompat Toolbar, I want to be able to change the color of the overflow menu icon on ActionMode change.

For example, the overflow icon will be white in normal Toolbar mode. And will turn black on ActionMode. So far, I have managed to change the background of the action mode as well as the title text. But I have yet to find a way to change the overflow menu icon color.

I know that there's an answer available:
[Change ActionMode Overflow icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720799/change-actionmode-overflow-icon)

I tried the first solution and I wasn't able to find the overflow icon.

The second solution, even with a 50L delay causes the overflow menu icon to flash the ActionMode's intended color for a brief split second that is very jarring.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Add the below line into your theme attribute:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: I don't know i have also second solution please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671677/android-appcompat-21-how-to-change-the-back-icon-and-the-overflow-icon-to-a-cu/33938229#33938229

Comment: Beware, this will also change the text colour in the bottom menu (which is shown by pressing the special key) on some devices. This can be a problem if `textColorSecondary` and the menu background are set to the same (or similar) colour.

Comment: Bette approach would be by creating a separate style for it:
`<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="AppTheme.MyTheme">
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>`

Comment: This will not result in a different colors in action mode and normal toolbar.

Comment: Setting your text color to a hard coded white (or any fixed color) will not allow it to reflect being activated or disabled, etc..   You really want that to be a color selector.

Answer (score 17):

This can be achieved by setting the `android:textColorSecondary` theme attribute.

For example, suppose you have the following toolbar, which uses the theme `MyToolbarStyle`:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  theme="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
/>
```

Next, define the style `MyToolbarStyle`, inheriting from `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar`. Finally, modify the color of the overflow icon by adding an item for `android:textColorSecondary`:

```xml
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#333333</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for answering... But the problem was that the overflow icon menu color is shared by the ActionMode's overflow icon and the Toolbar's overflow icon. The goal was to have a different color for both.

Comment: Now if you disable things in the actionBar, they will still be white.  You need a color selected, not a hard coded color.

Answer (score 12):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.Overflow.Icon</item>
 </style>

 <style name="ActionButton.Overflow.Icon" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
     <item name="android:src">@mipmap/yourwanticon</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: The only answer works perfectly not changing text color or menu items color - only overflow menu icon.

Answer (score 11):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonOverflow</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButtonOverflow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/brand_white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

create the above theme.set tint with your color and add this theme to the toolbar.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"/>
```

Comment: Best solution so far.

Answer (score 5):

Add this code on your res->styles.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarColored" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">YOUR_COLOR</item>
</style>
```

Then your 'ToolbarColored' style in your XML file like belove

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: doesn't change color of icons of `MaterialToolbar`

Answer (score 3):

To correctly change the color of your toolbar's overflow menu icon, set your toolbar's theme to an AppCompat dark ActionBar theme. For example:

In your res/values/style.xml file create a theme that inherits from AppCompat in this manner:

```
<style name="AppTheme.MyThemeName" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Now set your toolbar's theme to this theme:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="+id/my_toolbar_id
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/my_toolbar_height"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyThemeName">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here helped me change the overflow icon color of ActionMode independently from the overflow icon color of the normal Toolbar  (without resorting to case-by-case styling in code). After some trial and error, I thought that we might override `theme` attribute of ActionMode independently from Toolbar, and it worked!

In the base theme, we specify the style of action mode like usual:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Bridge">
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeStyle</item>
</style>
```

In our custom `ActionModeStyle` we do whatever styling we want, and also specify a `theme` attribute:

```
<style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="theme">@style/ActionMode.Theme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionMode.Theme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

`textColorSecondary` will also change the back button color, but we can easily override that one using `actionModeCloseButtonStyle`.

Comment: doesn't change color of icons of `MaterialToolbar`

Answer (score 2):

First make your custom style

```
 <style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Then just add it into your toolbar

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:titleTextColor="@color/white"
          app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the toolbar in your activity xml you can use something like this

```
toolbar?.navigationIcon?.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot. How to do it if the menu item contains actionLayout?

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomOverflowButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **white** overflow menu icon simply add
`android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` to your Toolbar layout code.

If you want the **dark** overflow menu icon use
`android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu"`

So final code is something like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/a_main_tb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
        />
```

Also, you should understand that it will change the color of the menu items also.