# Apply Color Filter to Action Overflow Icon at Runtime

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there any way to get the Action bar overflow icon drawable at runtime to apply a color filter?  I'm looking for something similar to menu.findItem(R.id.menu_id).getIcon() except for the 3 dot overflow so that I can do a .setColorFilter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. You just have to find overflow icon in view hierarchy. One good way is searching in `ViewGroup` returned by `getDecorView()`. You can search for it using [`findViewsWithText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewsWithText%28java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.view.View%3E,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) with flag `FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION`.

Sample code:

```
public static void setOverflowButtonColor(final Activity activity, final int visibleFontColor) {
    final String overflowDescription = activity.getString(R.string.abc_action_menu_overflow_description);
    final ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = decorView.getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            final ArrayList<View> outViews = new ArrayList<View>();
            decorView.findViewsWithText(outViews, overflowDescription, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
            if (outViews.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            TintImageView overflow = (TintImageView) outViews.get(0);
            overflow.setColorFilter(Color.CYAN);
            removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(decorView, this);
        }
    });
}

public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
    }
    else {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }
}
```

For more details see my answer in similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672844/2707179

Answer (score 0):

You cant get the `OverflowIcon` within the `onCreateOptionsMenu`, but you can still change the appearance of it at runtime so instead of applying a filter on it programatically you can create your own `OverflowIcon` image instead.

**sample:**

You can change the `overflow` icon within the style of your activity

```
<style name="YOUR_THEME" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
 <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/CustomOverflow</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
   <item name="android:src">@drawable/your_custom_overflow_image</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I am actually already doing that, but a new requirement makes it necessary to apply a custom color filter at run time.

Comment: @frenziedherring what new requirement, and be aware that overflow button only occurs when the devices doesnot have menu hardware button

Comment: It's a new requirement for the application I am writing, and I'm aware that the overflow won't be there if there's a hardware button.  If it is there, however, I want to be able to apply the color filter to it.  The color isn't known beforehand, so it's can't be applied in an XML theme in the compiled APK

Comment: @frenziedherring it is no go, android wont let you change the overflow icon on runtime, except if you are changing it within the style xml.