# Overflow dots not changing colour

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

The overflow dots with my activity remain white hence don't change colour when using the code below. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wc_bank);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

    //change background colour of action bar
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#66CCCC")));
    //change text colour of action bar
    actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000099'>Hello World</font>"));

    //change colour of action bar back arrow
    final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

    //enable and show action bar back arrow
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    final Drawable overflowDots = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha);
    overflowDots.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.piccadilly), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

Comment: Where are you actually using this Drawable?

Comment: Can you show us how you are using it? Right now I see you getting an instance of a Drawable and setting a color filter, but I don't see where you are using this drawable, say with an `ImageView` or `MenuItem`.

Comment: But *how*? Please post **the code** that you are using to set this Drawable in your `ActionBar`.

Comment: Just posted code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't doing anything with your tinted Drawable. You get an instance of your `abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha` icon and you set a ColorFilter on it, but then you aren't actually using that Drawable anywhere.

Unfortunately there also isn't a good way to set a `Drawable` object as your overflow menu icon. If you insist on doing this in your Java code, you can [use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106474/1253844) to accomplish that, but it is pretty hacky.

The preferred way is to use a custom style and the `android:actionOverflowButtonStyle` theme attribute to reference a Drawable *resource*. This means that if you use this option, you need to create a new asset with the correct color and include that in your drawable resource folders. Your theme will end up looking something like this:

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Your.Theme.OverflowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.Theme.OverflowStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/your_overflow_icon</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You could create a theme only used by that Activity. You can apply the `android:theme` to specific `<activity>` elements in your manifest.

Comment: Bear in mind that I am using the AppCompat theme for my app. Anything specific that I need to do?

Comment: Nope, I believe that attribute is the same there.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked for me. Please check the screenshot above.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated my answer, try changing the parent style for the Overflow style to `Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow`.

Comment: Now I'm lost. Could you check my screenshot to figure out what I need to change please?

Comment: I did, which is why I updated my answer. I changed the parent theme for `Your.Theme.OverflowStyle` to `@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow`.

Comment: Surprisingly, this work in 5.0+ but not 4.1. Dunno why.