# Set Toolbar Icon Colour Programmatically

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

How can I set the colour of icons (home and overflow menu icon) in a `Toolbar`/`AppBarLayout` *programmatically*?

I want to change the toolbar's colour scheme for a single fragment in an activity. Setting the `AppBarLayout`'s background to a light colour (e.g. light gray with `appBarLayout.setBackgroundResource(..);`) results in white icons and a white title which are barely visible.

Its layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

---

**[Solution found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36037707/447697)**

Comment: what do you have in @style/ToolbarStyle?

Comment: 3-dot menu icon is called overflow icon

Comment: @ootinii It shouldn't matter - I need to override that style through code in a particular fragment

Comment: @g2o Forgot the word - thanks!

Comment: did you want to change home icon or back icon ?

Comment: @g2o Both if possible

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change overflow icon is easy with support 23. Here is a method from [Lorne Laliberte answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33534039/4848308)

```
public static void setOverflowButtonColor(final Toolbar toolbar, final int color) {
    Drawable drawable = toolbar.getOverflowIcon();
    if(drawable != null) {
        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), color);
        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
    }
}
```

You can change your home as up passing your custom drawable..

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_drawable)
```

or changing its color

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to change more elements [here](https://snow.dog/blog/how-to-dynamicaly-change-android-toolbar-icons-color/) is good post to change all toolbar icons colors.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hey, this helped a lot! I used your first code snippet to change overflow button colour and the first code snippet from [the post you linked](https://snow.dog/blog/how-to-dynamicaly-change-android-toolbar-icons-color/) to change the colour of other toolbar views. I've accepted your answer because it was so helpful, but I'm going to add my own method that's a combination of a few pieces of code too.

Answer (score 6):

I've accepted the [most helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022041/447697) ([and commented on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020969/set-toolbar-icon-color-programmatically/36022041#comment59724298_36022041)) explaining that I used a combination of its linked code snippets to form a single `AppBarLayout`/`Toolbar` colouring method. It covers background, title, subtitle, back/drawer icon and overflow icon colours, as well as any custom `ImageButtons` added. Here's my result (*forgive the English 'colour' spelling(!)..*):

```
public static void colouriseToolbar(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, @ColorInt int background, @ColorInt int foreground) {
    if (appBarLayout == null) return;

    appBarLayout.setBackgroundColor(background);

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)appBarLayout.getChildAt(0);
    if (toolbar == null) return;

    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(foreground);
    toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(foreground);

    final PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter
            = new PorterDuffColorFilter(foreground, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);

        //todo: cal icon?
        Log.d(Globals.TAG, "view: "+i+" "+view.getClass().toString());

        //Back button or drawer open button
        if (view instanceof ImageButton) {
            ((ImageButton)view).getDrawable().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        }

        if (view instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ((ActionMenuView) view).getChildCount(); j++) {

                final View innerView = ((ActionMenuView)view).getChildAt(j);

                //Any ActionMenuViews - icons that are not back button, text or overflow menu
                if (innerView instanceof ActionMenuItemView) {
                    Log.d(Globals.TAG, "view (actionmenuitemviwe): "+i);

                    final Drawable[] drawables = ((ActionMenuItemView)innerView).getCompoundDrawables();
                    for (int k = 0; k < drawables.length; k++) {

                        final Drawable drawable = drawables[k];
                        if (drawable != null) {
                            final int drawableIndex = k;
                            //Set the color filter in separate thread
                            //by adding it to the message queue - won't work otherwise
                            innerView.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    ((ActionMenuItemView) innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[drawableIndex].setColorFilter(colorFilter);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Overflow icon
    Drawable overflowIcon = toolbar.getOverflowIcon();
    if (overflowIcon != null) {
        overflowIcon.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(overflowIcon);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on Android 10 and even if fixed this approach is likely to break in the future...

Answer (score 1):

You can change `home` as `up icon` by below code:

```
Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.back);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```