# How can I change the Toolbar three dots menu drawable colour or tint?

Tags: android

I am trying to change the background color of the three dots menu on the toolbar programmatically, how can I change that at run time?

I don't want to change it in XML because It has to be changed at run time.

```
getSupportActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources.getColor(R.color.red)))
```

The three dots needs to change color.

Answer (score 1):

Change overflow icon is easy with support 23. Here is a method from [Lorne Laliberte answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046903/changing-the-android-overflow-menu-icon-programmatically/33534039#33534039) and here is you can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020969/set-toolbar-icon-colour-programmatically).

```
public static void setOverflowButtonColor(final Toolbar toolbar, final int color) {
    Drawable drawable = toolbar.getOverflowIcon();
    if(drawable != null) {
        drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable.mutate(), color);
        toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
    }
}
```

You can change your home as up passing your custom drawable...

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_drawable)
```

or changing its color

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

**Note:**
If you want to change more elements [here](http://If%20you%20want%20to%20change%20more%20elements%20here%20is%20good%20post%20to%20change%20all%20toolbar%20icons%20colors.) is a good post to change all toolbar icons colors.

Comment: This looks great, but I am using getSupportActionBar how will I use that helper method?

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_drawable)` ypu can change by using this.

Comment: Thank you so much it works, you the best. I've been stuck with this for a week.

Comment: @karabomatsemela your welcome please mark this answer if it helped you.