# how change android activiy homeAsup arrow color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

how change android activity homeAsup arrow color ,
I find these style item

> homeAsUpIndicator
>
> actionOverflowButtonStyle

how can I change action bar homeAsUp Arrow and actionOverflowButton style

Answer (score 4):

The "up" affordance indicator is provided by a drawable specified in the homeAsUpIndicator attribute of the theme. To override it with your own custom version it would be something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

If you are supporting pre-3.0 with your application be sure you put this version of the custom theme in values-v11 or similar.

Comment: thanks, this is right , what I do before,but don't work, \n  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome</item>
         <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item> 

    </style>

Answer (score 2):

To change homeAsUp :

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                  R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                  R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                  R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
);
```

To change actionOverflowButton style refer to this post :
[Changing overflow icon in the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733312/changing-overflow-icon-in-the-action-bar)