# Set Color of action bar menu

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

How can I programmaticly set the color of the action bar menu.

I am talking about the three vertical dots that appear on the top right of the action bar.

How can I set the color of this programatically.

Here is what I have tried

[How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

[How to change the background color of Action Bar's Option Menu in Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you read/tried so far?

Comment: see above, but I can't find programatic answer

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733312/changing-overflow-icon-in-the-action-bar) for a solution using themes, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046903/changing-the-android-overflow-menu-icon-programmatically/22106474#22106474) for a semi-programmatic solution.

Comment: @stkent is there an easy way to set it to white? Like holo.dark.white I can't seem where to set that action bar theme

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9733538/1584654

Comment: @Joseph82 where is main theme definition?

Comment: You said that you was talking about the three vrtical dots (aka action overflow). Ok, maybe you was talking about the manu that appears when you click on the action overflow

Comment: @Joseph82 yes the action overflow, I want those three dots white?

Comment: ok, so you can use that link: look at ic_action_overflow and use your own icon (white)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66852/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-joseph82).