# android -How to make a custom drawer menu on custom actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using a custom actionbar . I use a layout for my actionbar . I've a navigationDrawer on my application and it works fine .Now I want to add another menu looks like this :

[image]

I want when I click on it ,it opens a small menu that has 3 rows .

we can do this with setting android:showAsAction="never" in menu.xml but I don't use android's default menu so I cant use that .

How can I make this menu on custom actionbar ?

Comment: you are looking for the `PopupMenu` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change this with styles from xml or dynamically. Hope this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733538/3864698