# Android, Change overflow icon in custom ActionBar?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-styles, overflow-menu

I have a custom action bar, as follows:

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.pt" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_pt</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_pt</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_pt</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.pt</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.pt.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/customicon</item>
</style>
```

But the Overflow Icon is not changing from the default three dots. How can I set it to the custom image?

I'm modelling it after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733312/changing-overflow-icon-in-the-action-bar) SO post, but still not working out.

From Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That post is years old and for the old Holo theme. I would highly suggest not to do this, you want a "common" Material design UI for users that using your app for the first time.

Comment: The custom icon is just a hamburger icon, which is well known as a drop-down menu icon. I'd like to use it, if there is a way, otherwise at least change the colors of the three dots. Nothing in the app is black, except those ugly dots. But still, I'd prefer the hamburger.

Comment: Yup, that did it! Except `@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow` instead of `@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow`

Comment: So called "hamburger icon" is not used for the overflow menu in Android, it's mostly used with the Navigation Drawer.