# How to change menu icon

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

I have the following menu that i declare in Main activity :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

 //... populate with menu.add()

}
```

The menu icon looks like 3 dotts and it's position is on the action bar on the right side. In my app i use Fragments and i want to change the menu icon ( the icon i press to open de menu items ) depending on the fragment it's in front.

How can i do that programmatically?

Also on some of my fragments i don't want the menu to appear. For this i use inside those fragments :

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
}
```

And i try to find a way using the menu var to change the icon of the menu. But i did not find a way.

So.... can you please show me how to change the menu icon programmatically?

Thanks,

Comment: did you mean the Navigation Drawer  ?

Comment: noup. that one i change it through : new ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Comment: In a defalut app : you press the menu icon ( those 3 dotts that i want to change whit other icon ) and it shows you 1 item call "settings"

Comment: Do you have this in your code , ??      `  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
this,                 
mDrawerLayout,         
R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close) `

Answer (score 0):

Look to this question:

[How to change the Option menu icon in the Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506184/how-to-change-the-option-menu-icon-in-the-action-bar)

Try this:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
     <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark</item>
     <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
     <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/action_menu_overflow_description</item>
</style>
```

**Update:**

To change it programatically see this question:
[Changing the Android Overflow menu icon programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046903/changing-the-android-overflow-menu-icon-programmatically)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: And how can i do it from code ? I wana change that icon from fragment to fragment

Comment: see this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046903/changing-the-android-overflow-menu-icon-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, what you mean is the `overflow` icon. This is how i do it :

```
<!--inside your styles.xml-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/overflow</item>
</style>

<style name="overflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/custom_overflow</item>
</style>
```

UPDATE :

To change it programatically : [Changing the Android Overflow menu icon programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046903/changing-the-android-overflow-menu-icon-programmatically)